# Запрос статьи с сервера

Tags: sql, ajax

Допустим, нужно сделать 10 ссылок на статьи. Ссылки выглядят так: картинка + первые строки соответствующей статьи.

Чтобы отобразить эти первые строчки, нужно целые статьи загрузить с сервера и потом вырезать их начало? Или есть менее ресурсозатратный способ(по количеству запрашиваемых данных)?

Comment: Можете обрезать текст, либо при SQL запросе, используя [SUBSTRING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) либо обрезать текст на бекенде.

Comment: Что конкретно имеется в виду под словом "сервер"?

Comment: andreymal, место, куда направляется запрос с фронтенда, чтобы получить данные из базы данных

Comment: Значит в этом самом месте у вас должна быть техническая возможность делать что угодно, в том числе вырезать ненужное